# Multiple DKIM records

Tags: email, spam, dkim

I have google (Google Apps for Business) as my primary email provider. But I use another company to do the marketing email campaigns. And since Google doesn't allow to export DKIM key, I would like to have separate DKIM selector for this 3rd party company that sends marketing campaigns. i.e. I will have 2 records:

> google._domainkey.yourdomain.com
>   3rd-party-company._domainkey.yourdomain.com

Is it the proper approach to the problem? Will the DKIM work fine in this situation?

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: It was already answered http://serverfault.com/questions/803232/double-dkim-dns-records

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double DKIM dns records](https://serverfault.com/questions/803232/double-dkim-dns-records)